# What is the ? in JavaScript and how does it work?

Tags: javascript, html

What is this line of code in JavaScript `x.style.backgroundColor = x.style.backgroundColor == "yellow" ? "pink" : "yellow";"`  in the program written below?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <body>

   <p>In this example, the setInterval() method executes the setColor()       function once every 300 milliseconds, which will toggle between two background   colors.</p>

   <button onclick="stopColor()">Stop Toggling</button>

   <script>
   var myVar = setInterval(function(){ setColor() }, 300);

   function setColor() {
   var x = document.body;
   x.style.backgroundColor = x.style.backgroundColor == "yellow" ? "pink" :    "yellow";
   }

   function stopColor() {
   clearInterval(myVar);
   }
   </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

> condition ? expr1 : expr2

Which is the same as:

```
if (condition) expr1;
else expr2;
```

So in your case:

```
x.style.backgroundColor = x.style.backgroundColor == "yellow" ? "pink" : "yellow"
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if (x.style.backgroundColor == "yellow")
    x.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
else x.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```